# Code::Blocks compiler not working

Tags: c, codeblocks

When I try to open Code::Blocks this message appears "Can't find compiler executable in your configuration search path's for GNU GCC compiler".
and I can't run any projects.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Either download codeblocks with compiler included (it exists a combo), or install a compiler separately, and/or configure codeblocks to point to your installed compiler. But first read installation procedure...

Answer (score 4):

Install MinGW if you haven't(it should come installed with Code::Blocks). Then run Code::Blocks go to `Settings->Compiler Setting->Toolchain executables` and press `Auto-Detect` .If auto detect doesn't work include the path yourself(find where you installed MinGW).Also make sure that in `Project-> Build options` you have selected the `GNU GCC` Compiler

Comment: Did you restart the Code::Blocks after detecting?

Comment: when i try to run any project this message appear "Target uses an invalid compiler; run aborted"

Comment: Are you sure you have MinGW installed since i think thats the only thing that can cause it. Also check if you have gcc.exe in MinGW folder