# Why Code Blocks 20.03 stops compiling and running? How to get it rework again?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I use Code Blocks 20.03, it was running without trouble but suddenly it stops compiling and running! Reinstallation did not work for me.  Here what happens -

1. When I click "build" nothing happens.
2. "Build and Run"  nothing happens.
3. "When It seems that this file has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?" When I press nothing happens.

Compiler set to C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW
I run windows 10, 64bit.

Solution from here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512775/codeblocks-compiler-not-working" did not work as compiler is already set!!
I have download the installer from here:
http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio Code :https://code.visualstudio.com/

I use this version of code::blocks:https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/17.12/Windows/codeblocks-17.12mingw-setup.exe/download?use_mirror=deac-ams&download=&failedmirror=kumisystems.dl.sourceforge.net

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.. I will try it for sure. It would also be good if I have the solution of the problem as I already have distributed this to my students!!